# Cannot overwrite Hive Scratchdir using Beeline

Tags: hive, ambari, beeline

When opening a hiveserver2 connection using beeline, setting the hive scratchdir is not working; I am running HDP 2.4 having `hive.server2.enable.doAs` enabled. When I execute

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/;principal=hive/_HOST@COMPANY.COM" \
  --hiveconf hive.exec.scratchdir=/tmp/user/somedir
```

I get a Ranger Security Permisson writing to `/tmp/hive`. The restricted properties don't contain `hive.exec.scratchdir`.

How can I configure/set/overwrite this setting on runtime?

Comment: The Hive documentation for server-side & client-side properties is here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

Comment: Since **Ranger** uses that property, _(1)_ you should have set a "ranger" tag on your question, and _(2)_ you probably have to set the property in Ambari, to be written into `hive-site.xml` used by HiveServer2 (and Ambari will probably flag it as "final" i.e. you cannot reset it dynamically in your JDBC session)

Comment: And maybe it's just a problem with the HDFS permissions on the `/tmp/user` that you want to use, e.g. "sticky bit" -- there are good reasons for sticking to default directories such as `/user/hive` for scratch dir (and `/user/mapred` for logs, etc. etc.)